# Swiperjs 1st appended slides behave OK but 2nd onward doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

Below are the swiperjs code that will behave like this:

1. If the slides qty is < 5, prev & next button will not show and also the swiper is not draggable.
2. If slides qty > 5, swiper become draggable, and prev & next button will show. Then swiper will scroll to last of the newly appended slide after .5s delay (with animation).

View on codepen https://codepen.io/grey-ooi/pen/WNZKozR

1st appended slide behave just fine(slide appended and scroll to it), but 2nd appended slide onward the .5s delay scroll to last slide doesn't seems to work anymore. It straigth away show the 2nd appended slide without scroll animation.

I'm grateful if you can point out what went wrong in the code, thank you!

```
var awayReplaySwiper = new Swiper('.awayReplaySwiper', {
            slidesPerView: 5,
            centeredSlides: false,
            spaceBetween: 4,
            observer: true,
            breakpoints: {
                // when window width is <= 499px
                499: {

                    spaceBetweenSlides: 8
                },
                

            },
            pagination: {
                //el: ".swiper-pagination",
                type: "fraction",
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: ".away-swiper-button-next",
                prevEl: ".away-swiper-button-prev",
            },
            on: {
                init: function () {
                    if (this.slides.length < 5) {
                        
                        this.allowSlidePrev = this.allowSlideNext = false; // disabling swiping
                        $(".away-swiper-button-prev").hide();  // hiding arrows prev&next
                        $(".away-swiper-button-next").hide();

                        // Second way:
                        // this.el.classList.add('swiper-no-swiping');
                        console.log('away btn less than 5');
                    }

                    if (this.slides.length > 5) {
                        $('.awayReplaySwiper').find('.swiper-wrapper').removeClass('less_than_five');
                        this.allowSlidePrev = this.allowSlideNext = true; // disabling swiping
                        $(".away-swiper-button-prev").show();  // show arrows prev&next
                        $(".away-swiper-button-next").show();
                        console.log('away btn more than 5');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            awayReplaySwiper.slideTo(awayReplaySwiper.slides.length);
                        }, 500);
                    }
                },
                observerUpdate: function () {
                    if (this.slides.length > 5) {
                        $('.awayReplaySwiper').find('.swiper-wrapper').removeClass('less_than_five');
                        this.allowSlidePrev = this.allowSlideNext = true; // disabling swiping
                        $(".away-swiper-button-prev").show();  // show arrows prev&next
                        $(".away-swiper-button-next").show();
                        console.log('away btn more than 5');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            awayReplaySwiper.slideTo(awayReplaySwiper.slides.length);
                        }, 500);
                    }
                    console.log('slides added');
                }


            }
        });
var appendAwayNumber = awayReplaySwiper.slides.length;
```

Here is the js code for appending slides to swiper above

```
document.querySelector(".append-away-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            awayReplaySwiper.appendSlide(
                    '<div class="swiper-slide"><a href="#" class="each_replay"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M9.70694 6.06984C9.24379 5.79188 8.82586 5.54105 8.47461 5.39538C8.10657 5.24274 7.60382 5.11618 7.10716 5.39739C6.6105 5.67859 6.46036 6.17481 6.40189 6.56894C6.34609 6.94507 6.34614 7.43251 6.3462 7.97266V16.0273C6.34614 16.5675 6.34609 17.0549 6.40189 17.4311C6.46036 17.8252 6.6105 18.3214 7.10716 18.6026C7.60382 18.8838 8.10657 18.7573 8.47461 18.6046C8.82586 18.459 9.2438 18.2081 9.70694 17.9302L16.4209 13.9018C16.86 13.6385 17.2595 13.3988 17.5423 13.1664C17.8421 12.92 18.1751 12.5504 18.1751 12C18.1751 11.4496 17.8421 11.08 17.5423 10.8336C17.2595 10.6012 16.86 10.3615 16.4209 10.0982L9.70694 6.06984Z" fill="#2B55E3"/><span>#' + ++appendAwayNumber + "</span></a></div>"
                    );

            setTimeout(function () {
                awayReplaySwiper.slideTo(awayReplaySwiper.slides.length);

            }, 500)
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this and got the problem solved!

```
slidesLengthChange: function () {
                        
                        this.update();
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            homeReplaySwiper.slideTo(homeReplaySwiper.slides.length);
                            console.log('animated');
                        }, 500);
                    }
```